# react-currency-format is not displaying some of the html elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrow-functions, currency-formatting

I am developing a amazon clone by watching a tutorial. I have created a subtotal component where is used imported and used react-currency-format. inside the currency format tag I have created a arrow function and added some html tags. this html tags are not displaying on the browser.
The code snippet written in the Subtotal.js component

```js
import React from 'react'
import './Subtotal.css'
import CurrencyFormat from "react-currency-format";

function Subtotal() {
  return (
    <div className='subtotal' >
     <CurrencyFormat
        renderText={(value) => (
            <>
                <p>
                Subtotal (0 items): <strong>0</strong>
                </p>
                <small className="subtotal_gift" >
                    <input type="checkbox" /> 
                    This order contains gifts
                </small>
            </>
        )}
        decimalScale={2}
        value={0}
        displayType={"Text"}
        thousandSeparator = {true}
        prefix={"$"}
    /> 
         
        <button>Proceed to checkout</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

the text inside the paragraph tag is not displaying on the browser. but 0 written inside the paragraph tag is displayed inside the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing "Text" to "text" (lowercase) at the CurrencyFormat displayType prop.

Answer (score 0):

Add line below the code : **export default Subtotal**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).